# What is the best possible way to get a merged branch is different than master

Tags: git, gitlab, branching-and-merging

I have started a job. I am responsible for updating the server with the latest commits as well. Forgive me if the question has been asked and I could not trace it.

There are two branches `master` and `develop`. In my case `develop` is the default branch.

I made a feature branch and pushed it to the remote repository. Now I don't remember that I made my feature branch from `master` or `develop` but the branch is merged in `develop` after feedback from client.

I logged in to server and checked the pointing branch by using `git branch` the branch pointer is on `master` I fetched the latest and took a pull but I got the message `Already up to date` But My code is not updated. But When I followed the same procedure on my local system it fetched the master and pulled the latest code. My local is also pointing to `master`

I checked onto `develop` on live but it is 132 commits behind I cannot make the mistake of fetching because the application can break. Kindly help me understand the concept of default and main branch and also How can I update server safely with only my feature branch

Comment: Is your feature a single commit or multiple commits?

Comment: If your code was merged to the develop branch and nothing has been added to the master branch, then it makes sense that your master would show `Already up to date` since nothing has been added?

Comment: @MB Yes your point is correct but the confusing part is that same fetching the branch and taking pull while staying in master has updated it on my local.

Comment: @QasimAli Maybe its possible that your local branch was outdated compared to the branch on the server?

Comment: @MB No my branch is up to date with remote

Comment: Although you can find a way to fix that through the git bash or terminal, it might be helpful if you use `Fork` gui, in this case, to see what happened and where the head is on local and remote.

Answer (score 0):

A [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) would only fetch commits, without merging to your current branch, so no code would be updated.

A [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) would fetch+merge.

> I cannot make the mistake of fetching because the application can break.

Fetching will not impact your application, will not move HEAD.

In your case, I recommend a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`, in order to *see* where HEAD is, on which branch.
From there, you can deduce where you need to be.